# Alternative to fixed arrays and pointers in C#

Tags: c#

Pretty straight forward, I'm trying to figure out the best alternative to hash (through XOR) the first bytes of a string using safe code. This is what I have at the moment:

```
    private static UInt32 HashString(String input)
    {
        Byte[] Buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

        fixed (Byte* pBuf = Buffer)
            return ((UInt16*)pBuf)[0] ^ 0x2ed6;
    }
```

Comment: That method doesn't have the `unsafe` keyword. Do you want to xor a memory location or the value of the first byte (so maybe it would be `fixed (Byte* pBuf = &Buffer[0]) { }`)? If that's the case, remove `fixed` and `return (uint)(buffer[0] ^ 0x2ed6);`. Or do you want to xor the first 4 bytes?

Comment: In that case, you can `return BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);`, to return the same thing `((uint*)pBuf)[0] ^ 0x2ed6;` would return, without `unsafe` in the method.

Comment: What is the question that you're asking? Where are you stuck?